# How to Launching an other app from an intent with different process?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-launcher, android-task

Actually, I'm trying to launch "App B" From "App A" through Uri intent, but that opens up in the same process of "App A" when I minimize the app it shows only one app in the background that is "App A" & "App B" is loading in that process.

**Code to Launch "App B" From "App A"**

```
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("MyappB://pt?user=userID&pass=Password"); 
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(uri);
    startActivity(intent);
```

**In-App B manifest file**

```
 <activity android:name=".common.controller.ParseDeepLinkActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data
                android:scheme="MyappB"
                android:host="pt"
                />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

it launches the Second App B but the process will be the same when I minimize, I won't see two apps in the background, it shows only App A in the background and loading App B in it.

How do I get the two separate process for App A & App B?

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.setComponent(ComponentName.unflattenFromString("MyappB://ptuser=userID&pass=Password"));
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: How to declared in the manifest of MyappB?
in the same way, I'm doing?